# How to write special characters into MySQL via PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, html, character-encoding

In my database in some fields the data is showing like as in following screenshots:

1. http://i31.tinypic.com/2637l9f.jpg
2. http://i27.tinypic.com/1ihh6d.jpg
3. http://i26.tinypic.com/2yklzb4.jpg
4. http://i31.tinypic.com/2vbshtf.jpg

I used `mysql_real_escape_string` while inserting my data into database  and `htmlspecialchars` while displaying.

Can any one tell me why they looking like this, and whats the solution?

Comment: Sorry, I may be going blind, but whats up with the data being in that format? EDIT: Ah, before they weren't links but were in a code block. Thought he was saying that the urls were being stored like the ones above!

Comment: @Stephen: when you've enough reputation you'll be able to view/edit other's message source. Click the blue timestamp link after `edited` here above and see.

Comment: @BalusC Thanks for the tip, although I did already know that. I just had a ditzy moment and thinking that the 'problem' was that the database was storing urls in plaintext, having not been encoded for webpages. Or something like that. I just expected someone to embed an image, not link to it! XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's [Mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake). Your PHP and MySQL code are not ready for [World Domination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode).

To fix it properly, go through [this cheatsheet](http://developer.loftdigital.com/blog/php-utf-8-cheatsheet) and ensure that every layer is using UTF-8.

---

The [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) basically only prevents you from [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) [attacks](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html) and the [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) basically only prevents you from [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) [attacks](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html). They do not assist in encoding or decoding the characters in any way. The character set used is responsible for that. Your problem is that you're not consistent in using the charset and/or that the charset you've chosen/used does not support the characters which the client entered and/or you'd like to use.